# sqlite3_key missing from header in iOS 11 framework

Tags: sqlite, encryption, ios11

SQLite.h in iOS 11 framework is missing sqlite3_key in the header. Has anyone noticed this? This is working fine in iOS 10.3.

Comment: Interesting ... Encryption Extension(SEE) is not available publicly. We have to purchase it at the cost of around $2000. Take cover when telling the customer.